# Calling generic static method locally while omitting class name

Tags: java, generics

This is the method i am going to call/invoke.

```
public static <N,E> void doGenericStatic2(N number, E element) {
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

This is the method where i am testing invoking the previous method (Both are located in the same class named `MyClass`)

```
    public static void testInvokeGenericMethodLocally() {
        doGenericStatic2(100, "Text");
//      <Integer,String>doGenericStatic2(100, "Text"); //Syntax error, insert "super ( ) ;" to complete Statement
        MyClass.doGenericStatic2(100, "Text");
        MyClass.<Integer,String>doGenericStatic2(100, "Text");
    }
```

Why does this particular case (second invoke test) `<Integer,String>doGenericStatic2(100, "Text");` generate a compile time error?

Comment: Are you asking why the designers decided to make it this way, or how you would know that it's this way? In other words, are you looking for "here is the part of the JLS that describes this behavior," or "why did they decide the behavior is such"?

Comment: I'll have a look at the spec but as a guess it's because your statement can't start with generics in order to distinguish between operators `<` and `>` and generic type definitions.

Comment: my output: `100
Text
100
Text
100
Text`

Comment: @JordiCastilla The question is why the commented out line, if it were not commented out, would cause a compile-time syntax error.

Comment: @yshavit compile-time and syntax error are not the same....

Comment: @yshavit I am asking because it's my habit to dig deep and ask. and it mostly served me well and made me able to learn new and important things. Hopefully this is the case with this question :).
I am looking for both.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Unless there's some subtlety I'm not understanding, a syntax error in a compiled language is one kind of compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in [JLS 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), which describes method invocation syntax:

```
MethodInvocation:
  MethodName ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
```

Note that the `[TypeArguments]` option is only available when the method comes after a "dotted thing" (my very technical name for it). The JLS does not specify why this is, though Thomas' comment, that it would otherwise be ambiguous as to whether the `<` is a TypeArguments start or a less-than, is probably correct.

Answer (score 2):

As yshavit already posted, the JLS defines `<Integer,String>doGenericStatic2(100, "Text");` to be illegal syntax (or to put it the other way round, it doesn't match the definition of legal syntax).

The reason for this is not stated here but most probably it is meant to make life of compiler builders/JLS implementors easier while not adding much to the developer (besides the requirement to add a class name, `super` etc. in front of the statement).

One could argue that it would be possible to distinguish between `1 < 2` and `<Integer, String>` for example because the latter statement starts with `<` and is followed by a type name while the former either contains literals, method invocations or variables.

Consider the following valid snippet:

```
int Integer = 1;
int String = 2;

System.out.println( Arrays.asList( 1 <Integer, String> getMeSomeIntBiggerThan2() ) ); //prints [false, false]
```

Although this is really bad design and somewhat constructed out of the blue the JLS allows it and compilers have to deal with it. You still should be able to distinguish between a generic type definition and an operation but why make things more complicated in order to allow for a syntax that isn't really needed?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example

```
    x<<A>m()
```

it could be interpreted as

```
    x<<A   >   m()
```

or

```
    x    <    <A>m()
```

if we allowed syntax `<A>m()`. While the compiler *can* pick a winner, most likely the 1st one due to lexing rules, it is too dangerous to have this kind of confusion.

-

*( generic method type argument ambiguity )*